# What packages can I remove from Xfce?

Tags: package-management, xubuntu, 18.04, xfce, ubuntu-studio

I am trying to slim down my Xubuntu installation. What Xfce specific packages can be removed without tanking the environment?

Comment: Which XFCE features and service do you not use?

Comment: @user535733 I want to strip it down to its most basic functionality, so environment, window manager, panel, settings manager (with settings), and anything else that is mission critical. I plan on adding back in anything I realise I want. So far most of my attempts have just tanked the environment.

Comment: XFCE is already pretty basic. "Most basic functionality" seems a matter of opinion, so I suggest defining it more thoroughly. Most folks consider services they use to be generally 'essential' and services they don't use to be generally 'bloat', and those services vary from user to user.

Comment: To avoid 'tanking' the environment, start by looking at the dependencies of the `xubuntu-core` metapackage. Any 'Depends' dependency should be removed with great care. Any 'Recommends' dependency is optional and should not destroy the environment.

Comment: @user535733 I will give that a go, Thank you :)